# Using find to count only directories that have a certain 3 files?

Tags: filesystems, find, filenames

Is it possible to use `find` to only return a result is 3 file names are present in that directory?

of course at the end we can use `wc -l` to tally them up...

but starting with some sort of a project root directory and then within just those subfolders that match  name / regex pattern try to list ones that have within them:

`file1.ext1` and `file2.ext2` and `*.ext3`

and then only count the directly with `wc -l` if all those files are present within it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run tests which aren’t built-in to `find` with `-exec` or `-execdir`, and use their result as a `find` test. In this case:

```
find . -name \*.ext3 -execdir /usr/bin/test -e file1.ext1 -a -e file2.ext2 \; -printf "%p\n" | sort -u | wc -l
```

This will look for files matching `*.ext3`, and for every one it finds, run `/usr/bin/test` in the containing directory to check whether `file1.ext1` and `file2.ext2` exist there too. If they do, it outputs the containing directory’s path. The output is then filtered to remove duplicates, and finally counted.

Comment: Why do you do a `sort -u`?  There shouldn't be more than one file with the same name right?

Comment: @leeand00 since we’re matching `*.ext3`, the same path can be present multiple times in the results: a directory containing *n* files matching `*.ext3`, as well as `file1.ext1` and `file2.ext2`, will appear *n* times.

Comment: So we're counting the number of directories that match the criteria.  Okay.